# GluonMobile TextField don't show keyboard

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

I try to do a application with GluonMobile and when I click on a TextField the keyboard don't show up.

I try a couple of thing I found on the web but nothing work.

I try puting argument in the VM option, nothing.

I run on Java8 with GluonMobile (with IntelliJ)
Thanks

UPDATE
This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.18'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:8.0.8'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.agathe.AgatheApp'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.2'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:\\Users\\aitech\\android-sdk'

    }

    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.agathe.**.*',
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

The FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<View fx:id="login" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="350.0" stylesheets="@login.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.agathe.views.LoginPresenter">
<StackPane fx:id="layout">

<VBox alignment="CENTER" fillWidth="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="350.0" spacing="25.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <JFXTextField fx:id="userId" labelFloat="true" prefWidth="235.0" promptText="Nom D'utilisateur" stylesheets="@login.css" />
            <JFXPasswordField fx:id="passId" labelFloat="true" prefWidth="235.0" promptText="Mot de passe" stylesheets="@login.css" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="loginBtn" styleClass="jfButton" prefWidth="150.0" text="Login" onAction="#tryConn"/>
         </children>

    <TextField fx:id="text"/>
      </VBox>

</StackPane>
</View>
```

The Controller

```
package com.agathe.views;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.jfoenix.controls.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.awt.*;


public class LoginPresenter {


    @FXML
    private View login;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField userId;
    @FXML
    private JFXPasswordField passId;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton loginBtn;
    @FXML
    private StackPane layout;
    @FXML
    private TextField text;


    public void initialize(){

    }

    @FXML
    public void tryConn(ActionEvent event){


    text.requestFocus();


//        JFXDialogLayout content = new JFXDialogLayout();
//        content.setHeading(new Text("Erreur"));
//        content.setBody(new Text("Le nom d'u"));
//
//        JFXDialog dialog = new JFXDialog(layout, content, JFXDialog.DialogTransition.CENTER);
//
//
//        JFXButton btn = new JFXButton("OK");
////        btn.setDefaultButton(true);
//
//        btn.setOnAction(actionEvent ->{
//            dialog.close();
//        });
//
//        content.setActions(btn);
//        dialog.show();

    }


}
```

And the view

```
package com.agathe.views;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginView  {

    public View getView() {
        try {
            View view = FXMLLoader.load(PrimaryView.class.getResource("login.fxml"));
            return view;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
            return new View();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that the TextField shouldn't be focused, as the keyboard shows/hide based on focus gained/lost. For testing, it is convenient to have a Button that can take the focus. Also, can you update to jfxmobile plugin 1.3.18 and try again?

Comment: Then post what you have done (build.gradle, basicView) and Android version and device where you are testing.

Comment: Hi! It's not working,
I update the plugins in the build.gradle. 
I put on a button click the text.requestFocus();

The textfield focus is gain when I click on the button but no keyboard.

Just to be clear I run the appliction on desktop for testing.

It's different if i try on my Android or on a iPhone?

Comment: I edit the first post. I can't reply with all the code.

Comment: On desktop there is no soft-keyboard like on Android/iOS. The JavaFX built-in keyboard is not used (though maybe you can try it). The app should be tested on mobile, to see the native keyboard. One last thing: if you use Gluon Mobile, you shouldn't mix it with JFoenix...

Comment: I put the Jfoenix in comment for the moment. The only thing it's the TextField are better imo on Jfoenix with the Int that will go over  and the button with the built in animation.

Ill try on my phone and let you know

Comment: Gluon Mobile has also a `TextField` similar to JFoenix. No need for other dependencies that might have issues building for mobile (Swing is not allowed for instance).

Comment: Ok ill try that. 
I just install the app on my phone and the textfield working...
I feel dumb sorry for all that just because I wanted to use another dependencies. 

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JoséPereda apps installed on Note 10+ 5G have display problems. I double-checked it using your 2048FX app. Display problems and combo box not able to change the selection problem.

Comment: @Sedrick Nothing to do with this question :)